# ADF accessing 2 different projects(Mobile Browser and Desktop Browser) in one appliction via the same url

Tags: mobile, browser, oracle-adf, trinidad

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? The idea is - application consists of two projects one of them is for mobile browser another is for desktop they have common model, user have to access two different projects via the same url depending on device he uses.

```
#{requestContext.agent.type == 'desktop'? 'richmobile': 'mobile'}
```

This kind of EL is used to change skinning depending on device. As I understand server should do approximately the same?

Comment: Can you provide more info please? Your have created 3 projects within a Fusion Web Application (one Model and two Views)? In which place did you put the EL ?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I created model(contains java files with core logic) and TrinidadViewController(contains .jsf pages(built using trinidad components), validation and locale bundles) projects. After I got a task to add ADF browser project(to expose the same logic using ADF faces). Later I was asked to make an access to both projects using one URL.

Solution:

To manage redirect operation index.html file has been added to the project. If browser gets this kind of URL - 127.0.0.1:7101/adf-mobile-browser-poc-TrinidadViewController-context-root/, it automatically redirects to index.html page. Index.html contains redirect operation code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function redirect() {
              if (!isMobile()) {
                  window.location="/adf-mobile-browser-poc-big-context-root/faces/first.jspx";
              }else {
                  window.location="/adf-mobile-browser-poc-TrinidadViewController-context-root/faces/first.jsf";
              }
          }

          function isMobile() {
              return (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i))
          };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="redirect()">
    </body>
</html>
```

isMobile() –checks if current platform is mobile or desktop. Redirect() –redirects to a specific page. The whole thing looks like:

1. accessing URL -
   127.0.0.1:7101/adf-mobile-browser-poc-TrinidadViewController-context-root/
2. user gets to index.html
3. depending on current device javascript
   loads particular page.